# Finding Z through normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

The City of Calgary reports that the number of vehicles that use the Crowchild Trail bridge various on weekdays. This variation can be modeled by the Normal distribution with a mean of 107500 vehicles and a standard deviation of 8800 vehicles per day. You pick a weekday at random and set out a traffic counter on both the north-bound and south-bound lanes of the Crowchild Trail bridge. At the end of a 24-hour period, you are to download the data from the traffic counter and add the two figures to represent the total vehicle usage,X

A) What is the probability that the total vehicle usage figure will be more than 120500 vehicles?

- I got P(X>120500) = P(Z> 1.477) =???*

I cant seem to figure out what it equals to

B)What is the probability that the total vehicle usage figure will be between 80000 and 101000?

- I did P( 80000 < x < 101000) = p(-3.125 < z < -0.739) = p(z< -0.739) - p(z< -3.125) = ???*

Comment: Have you tried to use the converse probability, like $P(Z>1.477)=1-P(Z\leq 1.477)$ - where $Z\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$ ?

Comment: Would this work with P(-3.125 < Z < -0.739)?

Answer (score 0):

Here, $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu = 107500, \sigma^2 = 8800^2)$. Hence 
\begin{equation}
f_{X}(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \exp \left[ - \dfrac{(x - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^{2}}\right].
\end{equation}

Assuming, $z = \dfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma} \in Z$, then $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ and hence,
\begin{equation}
f_{Z}(z) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp \left[ - \dfrac{z^2}{2}\right].
\end{equation}

Hence, 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X > 120500) & = \mathbb{P}(Z > 1.47) \\
& = \int_{1.47}^{\infty} f_{Z}(z)\, dz \tag{actual lower limit should be $1.47^{+}$}\\
& = Q(1.47) = 0.0708.
\end{align}
where $Q(\cdot)$ is the $Q$-function. (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function) for details).

Similarly,

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(80000 < x < 101000) & = \mathbb{P}(-3.125 < z < -0.739) \\
& = \int_{-3.125}^{-0.739} f_{Z}(z)\, dz \\
& = \int_{-3.125}^{\infty} f_{Z}(z)\, dz - \int_{-0.739}^{\infty} f_{Z}(z)\, dz \\
& = Q(-3.125) - Q(-0.739) = 0.2291.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You don't say whether you are supposed to use printed normal tables or software to evaluate the probabilities.

From a printed normal table you can find that $P(Z \le 3.125) \approx 0.999$
and $P(Z \le .74) \approx 0.770.$ So $P(.739 \le Z \le 3.125) \approx 0.229.$
By the symmetry of the standard normal distribution about $0,$ you also
have $P(-3.125 \le Z \le -.739) \approx 0.229.$ Some rounding is necessary
to use printed tables. With interpolation you might 'squeeze out' slightly greater
accuracy. In R statistical software one obtains $0.2290645,$ which is greater
accuracy than would be needed in this kind of practical application.

```
diff(pnorm(c(-3.125, -.739)))
## 0.2290645
```

In terms of the standard normal distribution, the probability you want
is represented by the area between the two blue vertical lines, or the (equal)
area between the two red ones.

[image]

With only slightly more intricate use of the software, one can avoid standardization:

```
diff(pnorm(c(80000,101000), 107500, 8800)))
## 0.2291749
```

In principle, this should be *exactly* the same as the previous answer, but I suppose some rounding
was involved in getting .739 and 3.125.